# Convert row to column when data are not numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a Question table, which has a unknown number of questions.(first table in the figure)

I also have an AnswerSheet table, which records student's answer to question.(second table in the figure)

[image]

```
Create table Question
(
    Id int,
    Text nvarchar(50),

    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

Create table AnswerSheet
(
    StudentId int,
    QuestionId int,
    Answer nvarchar(50),

    PRIMARY KEY (StudentId,QuestionId),
    FOREIGN KEY (QuestionId) REFERENCES Question (Id)
)

insert into Question
values(1,'What''s your age'),
      (2,'What''s your gender'),
      (3,'When do you go home'),
      ....


insert into AnswerSheet
values(500,1,'20'),
      (500,2,'Male'),
      (500,3,'5:00pm'),
      (501,1,'50'),
      (502,2,'I don''t know@@'),
      ....
```

How do I write a SQL to generate a table like this?

```
StudentId    What's your age    What's your gender    When do you go home ...
---------    ----------------   -------------------   -------------------
500          20                 Male                  5:00pm              ...
501          50                 NULL                  NULL
502          NULL               I don''t know@@       NULL                ...
```

I feel [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) is promising but I'm not sure how to use it especially `PIVOT` requires an aggreation function but my data are not numbers.

Comment: did you check this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9621aea8-71f1-475c-951b-20403d4850a7/pivot-table-with-no-numeric-aggregation?forum=transactsql

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4807/1

Comment: @FLICKER Good searching skill, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to go Dynamic

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select ',' + QuoteName(Text) From Question  Order by ID For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 

Select  @SQL = '
Select *
From (
        Select StudentID
              ,Col       = B.Text
              ,Value     = A.Answer
         From AnswerSheet A
         Join Question B on A.QuestionID=B.ID
     ) A
 Pivot (max(Value) For [Col] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

```
StudentID   What's your age What's your gender  When do you go home
500         20              Male               5:00pm
501         50              NULL               NULL
502         NULL            I don't know@@     NULL
```

**If it Helps, the Generated SQL Looks Like This**

```
Select *
From (
        Select StudentID
              ,Col       = B.Text
              ,Value     = A.Answer
         From AnswerSheet A
         Join Question B on A.QuestionID=B.ID
     ) A
 Pivot (max(Value) For [Col] in ([What's your age],[What's your gender],[When do you go home]) ) p
```

Comment: @LoveRight I learn something new everyday.  Any aggregation function can be applied.   --- Happy it helped.

Answer (score 1):

*I know this question is answered by accepted one, but I hope this approach helps others.*

simply you can achieve your goal **without** using `Pivot`, via using `Group by` as next:-

```
Select  b.StudentId,
     Min(Case a.text When 'What''s your age' Then b.answer End) 'What''s your age',
     Min(Case a.text When 'What''s your gender' Then b.answer End) 'What''s your gender',
     Min(Case a.text When 'When do you go home' Then b.answer End) 'When do you go home'
from Question a inner join AnswerSheet b 
on a.id = b.Questionid
Group By StudentId
```

and you mentioned **unknown number of questions**, so the next code for dynamic:-

```
DECLARE @DynamicQuestions VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @DynamicQuestions =  Stuff(
(SELECT N' Min(Case a.text When''' + replace (Text,'''','''''')
+ ''' Then b.answer End) '''
+ replace (Text,'''','''''') + ''','
FROM Question FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'')

select @DynamicQuestions = 
left(@DynamicQuestions,len(@DynamicQuestions)-1) -- for Removing last comma


exec ('Select  b.StudentId, '+ @DynamicQuestions +
'from Question a inner join AnswerSheet b
on a.id = b.Questionid
Group By StudentId' )
```

**Result**:-

```
StudentId   What's your age What's your gender  When do you go home
500             20              Male                5:00pm
501             50              NULL                NULL
502             NULL        I don't know@@          NULL
```

Comment: Your answer is fine, I just want to point out that if you add the comma to the beginning of your subquery inside `stuff()` instead of a blank space, then you don't need to do the middle part where you remove the trailing comma.